# Android meter/bar for user input

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to make a meter/bar that the user can use in order to choose a specific value (for example; when the user wants to rate something between 1-10 etc). By sliding the bar left the value gets smaller and vice versa. Any ideas/hints to implement something like this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You probably have already looked at it but the 'Seek Bars and Sliders' is the default for this kind of control http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/seek-bars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **SeekBar**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Drop a SeekBar in your layout and get a handle on it in your code.  You can react to changes in the SeekBar by implementing a `OnSeekBarChangeListener`.

Here's a snippet to get you going:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
          int progress = 0;

          @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
              progress = progresValue;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changing seekbar's progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              textView.setText("Covered: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       });
```